# Alternative for findEntity(named:) method to find a specific model in RealityKit?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

So I asked a question a couple of days ago which Andy Jazz kindly [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76138677/how-to-make-grouped-objects-in-one-reality-composer-scene-draggable/76141035#76141035). So I have been playing with the answer, and although I was able to implement a solution, it is incomplete because the method he used, was `findEntity(named:)` using RealityKit. While I used Reality Composer on my own answer.

**Problem #1: `findEntity(named:)` method doesn't work on Reality Composer when you have multiple objects.** So I arrived at the realization the using the findEntity(named:) method doesn't work. Because all the objects within the scene are named `"simpBld_root"`, it doesn't work to trigger what I want to trigger.

**Problem #2: When using the parenting notation, I am doing a trial and error because I don't really understand what is what.**
How can I call each object? This is also a consequence of my own inability to correctly understand WHAT to call from Reality Composer because I don't think I really understand how the parenting notation applies in reality composer. The picture below is the Scene I am working printed on the console.

[image]

Below is an example I made work, where instead of Andy's solution for findEntity(named: ) I used children[0]

This is the code I tried, when using the findEntity() method that did NOT work:

```
let redBoardModelEntity =  cubesAnchor.redBoard?.findEntity(named: "simpBld_root") as! ModelEntity
let greenCubeModelEntity =  cubesAnchor.greenCube?.findEntity(named: "simpBld_root") as! ModelEntity
let blueCubeModelEntity =  cubesAnchor.blueCube?.findEntity(named: "simpBld_root") as! ModelEntity
```

And this is what I ended up with, that worked, meaning, it showed all the objects and the entire thing dragged together. [See pic below, followed by code]

[image]

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                
        let boxAnchor = try! Experience.loadBox()
        arView.scene.anchors.append(boxAnchor)            
    
        let cubesAnchor = try! Experience.loadCubes()
        arView.scene.anchors.append(cubesAnchor)
        print (cubesAnchor)
        cubesAnchor.actions.behavior.onAction = handleTapOnEntity(_:)            
        
        let redModel =  cubesAnchor.children[0].children[0]
                  
        let group = ModelEntity() as ModelEntity & HasCollision
        group.addChild(redModel)
        // group.addChild(blueCubeModelEntity)
        // group.addChild(greenCubeModelEntity)
        
        group.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
        self.arView.installGestures(.all, for: group)
        
        let shape = ShapeResource.generateBox(width: 1, height: 1, depth: 1)
        let collision = CollisionComponent(shapes: [shape],
                                             mode: .trigger,                                               
                                           filter: .sensor)
        group.components.set(collision)
        
        let anchor = AnchorEntity()
        anchor.addChild(group)
        anchor.scale = [5,5,5]
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)            
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0){
            // self.arView.scene.anchors.removeAll()
            let coneAnchor = try! Experience.loadCone()
            self.arView.scene.anchors.append(coneAnchor)
            coneAnchor.actions.behavior.onAction = handleTapOnEntity(_:)                    
            // print(cubesAnchor)                
        }                          
        
        boxAnchor.actions.behavior.onAction = handleTapOnEntity(_:)
            
        func handleTapOnEntity(_ entity: Entity?){
            guard let entity = entity else { return }
            
           // self.myEntity = entity
           // self.myEntity?.isEnabled = false    
        }            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Traversing children entities (nodes)

According to diagram, your models are called `greenCube`, `redBoard` and `blueCube` respectively. Thus, the simplest way to get any ModelEntity from Reality Composer's scene hierarchy is to apply `findEntity(named:)` method followed by access to its sub-children.

```
let model = cubesAnchor.findEntity(named: "greenCube")?.children[0] as! ModelEntity
```

...or, thanks to the Reality Composer's naming scheme:

```
let model = cubesAnchor.greenCube?.children[0] as! ModelEntity
```

Names `greenCube`, `redBoard` and `blueCube` are entities' names. All three models have a name `simpBld_root`. So, you can rename each ModelEntity if you like.

```
model.name = "Green_Cube_Model"

print(cubesAnchor.findEntity(named: "greenCube")!)
```

Result in Xcode's console:

```
▿ 'greenCube' : Entity, children: 1
  ⟐ Transform
  ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
  ▿ 'Green_Cube_Model' : ModelEntity         // New name
    ⟐ PhysicsBodyComponent
    ⟐ Transform
    ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
    ⟐ CollisionComponent
    ⟐ ModelComponent
```

Now you are able to get each ModelEntity via its unique name:

```
let green = cubesAnchor.findEntity(named: "Green_Cube_Model") as! ModelEntity
```

Or you can go through the [chain of children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68404663/realitykit-hiding-and-showing-parts-meshes-of-usdz-model/68411215#68411215).

---

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit
    
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let scene = try! Experience.loadTwoBoxes()
        
        // MODEL 001 
        let model001 = scene.findEntity(named: "redCube")?.children[0] as! ModelEntity & HasPhysicsBody
        model001.position.y = 1.0
        model001.physicsBody = .init()
        model001.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
        
        // MODEL 002       
        let forRenaming: Entity = scene.findEntity(named: "blueCube")!
        forRenaming.children[0].name = "Blue_Cube_Model"
        print(forRenaming)
    
        let model002 = scene.findEntity(named: "Blue_Cube_Model") as! ModelEntity & HasPhysicsBody
        model002.position.y = 1.0
        model002.physicsBody = .init()
        model002.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)

        arView.scene.anchors.append(scene)
    }
}
```