# RealityKit: Applying materials to a portion of an imported USDZ model

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, realitykit, reality-composer-pro

I have been doing research on this topic for a while, and I am completely stumped.

I have loaded a USDZ file into my project with the following code:

```
let coastRanges = try? ModelEntity.loadModel(named: "CoastRanges")
```

This is a model with multiple parts ("sub-models") inside of it, just like you would expect from a modeling software.

It's a coastal scene with a general landscape, but also an ocean, rocks, etc. Of course, all of these parts need to have different materials.

In my modeling software, I did not add any materials as I wanted to add my own materials through RealityKit to have finer control over the details of my model.

I played around with the model in Reality Composer Pro before exporting it as a USDZ:

[image: A screenshot of a model hierarchy in Reality Composer Pro]

However, I have an issue.

I want to add materials I created in code to certain parts of the model. The rocks, ocean, etc. need to have completely different materials.

I believe I need to access the children of the mesh, but I can't figure it out. Every time I try to print out `coastRanges.children`, the result is nil.

What am I doing wrong and how can I do this?

EDIT:

I do want to add that this is not a project for visionOS. This is a project for iPadOS and Mac Catalyst.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77861134/how-to-add-a-simple-material-to-a-existing-modelentity-in-realitykit/77881827#77881827) and its comments will definitely help you.

Comment: Hi there, I think I found that post already. Is what I am doing even possible? I am looking at the Dioramas project, but it's all for visionOS. Is my way of thinking correct? Or should I be setting this up in a different way? I'm struggling because Reality Composer isn't really set up for anything but visionOS at the moment. So, I thought just having one USDZ would be the way to go right now, until I could have an rkassets folder working properly... but I will have to wait until WWDC for that.

Comment: Use `Entity` instead of `ModelEntity` when using `loadModel(...)` method. And then, use downcasting to ModelEntity when you need a part of a model to assign a new material.

Comment: Ok. I will look over your post and let you know if it works out. Should I be using Reality Composer Pro at all? I created my model in Cinema 4D and thought to use it just to double check the hierarchy. But, I guess I don't need to actually change anything. I guess I am part of the group of people where my workflow is ahead of its time... waiting for Composer Pro support for non visionOS apps very much!

Comment: You can easily continue working with non-Pro [Reality Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76748779/can-we-use-reality-composer-pro-for-arview/77512647#77512647) in Xcode 15.

Comment: Ok. The only problem is, that I've searched for that in the past and I am confused on why it's not available in developer tools... even on Xcode 15.2. I read somewhere that other people cannot find it as well. What happened to Reality Composer on Mac? I only have it for iPadOS and iOS.

Comment: As my post says, you need Xcode 14 to get a non-Pro macOS Reality Composer.

Comment: I read through your answer. It looks like it works! Thanks for the help! :)