# Swift Playgrounds: How to add HDRI in a non AR RealityKit project?

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, swift-playground, realitykit

I am creating a RealityKit project on Swift Playgrounds in Xcode, but I am using it in a perhaps less common way. I am using RealityKit but without AR, which is possible by an [initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/arview/init(frame:cameramode:automaticallyconfiguresession:)) of `ARView`.

As such, I am not using the camera at all. Thus, I need my own lighting in a virtual scene just like a SceneKit project. There are a couple of lighting options in RealityKit, but the best one for my use cases is using an HDRI (image based lighting).

I found this documentation on how to add one in a typical Xcode project:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/environmentresource#Creating-a-Skybox-Folder

It states:

- I need to create a folder with a .skybox extension. I can do that, of course.
- I need to place a single image inside the folder, my HDRI file. No problem.
- I need to drag this folder to the Xcode project file navigator. Alright...

I have a problem.

I am prompted to create a folder reference (not a group) and add it to my app's target.

"At build time, Xcode compiles the image for use as an environment resource and inserts the result into the app bundle."

I don't know what to do. I am not using an Xcode project. I am using an Xcode Playground app playground (swiftpm).

The typical prompt when adding the folder to the project file navigator does not show up. Does this matter? Is there another way to add an HDRI to Xcode so I can use this for an app playground?

I really do not want to manually add lighting in RealityKit, and don't even know if that could replicate an HDRI.

Any thoughts on this? Other ways to achieve this? Mixing SceneKit? That sounds like a nightmare. I've thought about some very creative solutions!

Edit: Could I do something with the model I import? I am using Cinema 4D. Could I also perhaps do something in Reality Composer or even Reality Converter? Reality Composer Pro? (this isn't a visionOS app though). What other options could I use to replicate an HDRI in RealityKit? HDRIs are particularly useful because they're simple and manual lighting just doesn't seem to replicate it.

Comment: If you can share the code you have and your approach I could try to help.

Comment: Hello! I don't believe this is a question that has to do with code, it's more of me being uncertain this is possible in my context, as I am using a Swift Playgrounds app playground. Also, thanks for answering my question about the view pinning, I will take a look at it. In the mean time, I have just posted yet again another question. Thanks for all your help! :)

Comment: Just curious about your setup, I don’t know the answer to this one. I would literally just play around and see if I can figure it out. ARKit/RealityKit are not my strong areas just making a huge push to work on the frameworks lately. If I can see what you have I would be further down than having to recreate my own. But NP just an offer. BTW let me now how the pinning works.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't have much of a setup for this one. To me, it sounds like I had a problem because I am not using a typical Xcode project. I'm using an app playground. This one isn't too big of a deal. I will say, if you're making a push to RealityKit, I would love to know if you have any insight to my more recent question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77924132/realitykit-applying-materials-to-a-portion-of-an-imported-usdz-model), because I've been stuck for days on that one. I've looked at a ton of posts on that one! I'm also new to the framework, so I've been asking a lot lately.

Comment: I saw it, I no idea on that one. My instinct is that you can’t do it in reality kit because setup seems to be done in composer. Maybe there? Also, there is the diorama sample on the Apple website that dives a little deep maybe you can find a clue there. There was some other question on here that talked about meshes recently that may have a clue too. You can search the tag.

Comment: Just found the question I was thinking about it is yours too.

Comment: I don't know. I have a feeling you can do it... because why else would children exist? I found this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68404663/realitykit-hiding-and-showing-parts-meshes-of-usdz-model). I watched a session that basically explains that when you load a model, the hierarchy should come with it (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/hashierarchy). I've watched the diorama session, but they still had a material applied in Composer Pro to begin with. My issue is that Composer Pro limits materials. No access to the UnlitMaterial, etc. in the app. So I'm limited.

Comment: Maybe there is something that needs to be done when you create the usdz to expose it as a child.

Comment: Also: Reality Composer Pro (of course) is very new and seems to primarliy focus on visionOS right now. I hope that can change next WWDC. As such, I can't use the Shader Graph interface as any custom materials from there do not appear (they're just gray) in an iOS/macOS app. They work perfectly in visionOS. So, Composer Pro is really just an organizer for my purposes (iPadOS + Catalyst). This is why I thought making materials in code would be a great solution. The issue isn't making the materials, it's accessing certain parts of the model. I don't know why, but I still have faith I can do this.

Comment: You can do it! You can do it!

Comment: Ha! This has been a little challenging, because some of the technology (especially with Reality Composer Pro) is SUPER new. I'll keep you posted if I figure it out, because something like that could honestly be really helpful, I think. Thanks! :)

Comment: Your encouragement worked! I figured it out! I was pretty close, but not quite there. The answer is a bit messy and I had to make some adjustments, but it is a thing you can do! (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77924132/realitykit-applying-materials-to-a-portion-of-an-imported-usdz-model)

Comment: Glad to hear, you should answer the question, that would be incredibly helpful.